# Как правильно перенести слово "можно"?

Tags: орфография, перенос

Ребенку исправили МО-ЖНО на МОЖ-НО. Разве в данном случае не допускается разный способ переноса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитель, видимо, руководствовался очень старыми правилами, не рекомендующими отрывать одну букву от корня. Сейчас правила переноса гораздо более либеральны, в принципе возможны оба варианта. Хотя "учительский" предпочтительнее.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Но всё-таки нежелательно разрушать корень.

Answer (score 0):

Допускаются оба варианта переноса. И, как мне кажется, здесь нет разрушения корня. К примеру, слово "старый" переносится СТА-РЫЙ. Конечно, здесь нет рядом два согласных, но ведь "Р" относится к корню точно так же, как и в слове "можно" -  буква "Н"

Answer (score 0):

Грамотнее мож - но.